# Why does this jail command not work? The bot is online but it still wont work "other commands work btw"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I made a discord jail command and it doesn't work the bot is online but it doesn't work for some reason "Other commands work"

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)  
async def jail(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    color = 0xFFB6C1
    jailed_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="jailed")
    if not jailed_role:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description="Jail role not found, creating one.", color=color)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        try:
            jailed_role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="jailed")
      
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Jail role created", color=color)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description="Bot does not have permission to create the 'jailed' role.", color=color)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        await jailed_role.set_permissions(channel, view_channel=False)
    if jailed_role not in member.roles:
        for role in member.roles:
            if role != jailed_role:
                try:
                    await member.remove_roles(role)
                except discord.Forbidden:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description=f"Bot does not have permission to remove the role {role.name} from {member.mention}.", color=color)
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    return
        try:
            await member.add_roles(jailed_role, reason=reason)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Jailed!", description=f"{member.mention} has been jailed!", color=color)
            embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description=f"Bot does not have permission to assign the 'jailed' role to {member.mention}.", color=color)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description=f"{member.mention} is already jailed.", color=color)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I tried alot of stuff but nothing seems to work, it would be great if someone would be able to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  "I tried alot of stuff but nothing seems to work"  Please clarify what you have tried.  What happens when you run the jail command?  "Doesn't work" could mean it crashes.  Or it means it does something else or it does absolutely nothing?  You'll need to debug the code and figure out how the code works.  ie. find out which lines are executed and which are ignored given the input you put.

Comment: I run it and it logs in but when i do $jail @user it doesn't return anything and it doesnt create a role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.. only issue I see with your code is that the jailed permissions are set everytime you give the role to someone. Theoretically you only need to do it once - when you create the role.

Also note that I've added an optimization to avoid the removing of the "@everyone" role since that role can not be removed and will cause an error.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)  
async def jail(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    color = 0xFFB6C1
    jailed_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="jailed")
    if not jailed_role:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description="Jail role not found, creating one.", color=color)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        try:
            jailed_role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="jailed")
      
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Jail role created", color=color)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description="Bot does not have permission to create the 'jailed' role.", color=color)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
    
    overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
    overwrite.update(read_message_history = False, read_messages = False)
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(jailed_role, overwrite=overwrite) # set the permissions for each channel
    if jailed_role not in member.roles:
        for role in member.roles:
            if role != jailed_role:
                try:
                    if role.name == "@everyone": # will skipp @everyone since this role cant be removed
                        continue
                    await member.remove_roles(role)
                except discord.Forbidden:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description=f"Bot does not have permission to remove the role {role.name} from {member.mention}.", color=color)
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    return
        try:
            await member.add_roles(jailed_role, reason=reason)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Jailed!", description=f"{member.mention} has been jailed!", color=color)
            embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description=f"Bot does not have permission to assign the 'jailed' role to {member.mention}.", color=color)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed!", description=f"{member.mention} is already jailed.", color=color)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```